# Cumulative hotfixes installation on OnPrem and PaaS instances

Tags: sitecore-managed-cloud

We have one known issue in Sitecore 10.2 i.e. **[Retrieving the child items of resource items is not thread-safe](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001823)**

Sitecore provided the cumulative hotfix for it i.e. [Cumulative hotfix for Sitecore XP 10.2](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001439) and it's available for both `XP and XP 10.2 instances`.

That such hotfixes are not intended to be installed using the Installation wizard.

Sitecore provided the following articles describing how to install the hotfixes for OnPrem and PaaS instances:

- [Install a Sitecore XP pre-release using SIF](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/install-a-sitecore-xp-pre-release-using-sif.html)
- [Deploy a Sitecore XP pre-release to a PaaS solution](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/deploy-a-sitecore-xp-pre-release-to-a-paas-solution.html)

Does anyone have installed the same on Sitecore 10.2 on OnPrem and PaaS? Please provide some more detailed instructions on OnPrem and PaaS.

The application has been deployed with Sitecore Managed Cloud Service(Azure PaaS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have performed the below approach to install a `Cumulative Hotfix`:

1. Create one separate project in your solution named `SitecoreHotfix.Patch` or any other name convenient for you.
2. Add all the cumulative hotfix package files in the same project with the correct file or folder path.

[image]

**Note:** You will need to tweak your `CI/CD pipeline` in such a way that these Hotfix project artifacts deploy at the end otherwise hotfix files will be overwritten, and you will start facing yellow error pages.

For more details see the blog post: [Sitecore Cumulative Hotfixes Installation on OnPrem and PaaS](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/05/sitecore-cumulative-hotfixes-installation-onprem-and-paas.html)